# VS2017 travando em modo design

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio

Boa tarde a todos.

De uns dias pra cá tenho enfrentado um problema no VS2017 que está me irritando um bocado!!

Possuo um form com um usercontrol desenvolvido por mim e alguns grids. Um desses grids era vinculado à um datasource apontado para uma classe.

Como a regra de negócio mudou, apaguei o datasource e criei outro baseado na nova classe. À partir disso, toda vez que eu mudo meu windows form de classe para modo design o VS congela e só consigo fechar pelo gerenciador de tarefas!

Isso não acontece apenas nesse form em específico, mas agora TODOS os forms do projeto e dos outros projetos da solução estão causando o mesmo problema.

Para deixar isso mais hilário ainda, se eu abro o form no modo design e navego por ele usando a janela de Estrutura de Tópicos de Documento, consigo selecionar os componentes tranquilamente e fazer meu trabalho, porém se por algum motivo eu clicar diretamente no form ou em qualquer componente dentro dele, trava tudo e só fecha novamente pelo gerenciador de tarefas.

Eis o que já tentei:

- Desvincular a solução do TFS e vincular novamente;
- Restaurar pacotes NuGet;
- Debugar meu usercontrol dentro do próprio VS (tudo funcionando corretamente);
- Remover meu usercontrol do form e tentar abrir (continua com o mesmo problema).

Olhando pelos fórums da Microsoft, sempre existe aquela resposta padrão: reinicie o computador até que ele pegue fogo, limpe a pasta de arquivos temporários, limpe o cache do windows, dos navegadores, do seu e-mail, do seu celular e da sua mesa, que isso foi corrigido na versão tal, que tem que fazer windows update e mais um monte de babaquice!

Alguém já passou por esse problema e teria uma luz para me dar nesse caso? Já informo que desinstalar Visual Studio e instalar novamente está fora de questão, do contrário eu já teria feito isso!!!

Obrigado!

Comment: Meu primo estava com um caso parecido e resolveu apenas reinstalando tudo, infelizmente.

Comment: Consegui resolver com devenv /ResetSettings. Tive que reinstalar alguns componentes, porém demorou muito menos do que reinstalar o VS.

É realmente lamentável esse tipo de bug a essa altura do campeonato. Esse problema é recorrente e achei posts similares desde a versão 2010!